# Excel - Updating a .xlsb file when saving a .xlsx file

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2011

I work on Excel for Mac 2011.

Sometimes, for no apparent reason, I can't open one file I saved in .xlsx. I did some research and found it was a bug. The only workaround I found is to save the file in a .xlsb format. So that I can open it and save it in .xlsx.

This is my "in case the bug reappears" strategy. While working well, it is time consuming. Every time I want to update the .xlsx file I have to save two files (one in .xlsx and one in .xlsb).

Is there a way every time I save my .xlsx file the .xlsb file get updated automatically?

Comment: Why not just use the xlsb all the time? It functions basically the same as the xlsx file. Then re-save as xlsx if you need to distribute it.

Comment: Thats's a great idea! I think I came to the conclusion I wanted to have a copy in a different format because I experienced issues in .xslx and .xslb formats.